# how to get DataValue of dropdownlist in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a problem as subject said.

i have a Table courses in sql server Fields are courseID and course.

what i want is list the course in dopdown and i succeeeded but what i'm not able to do is when i select a course from dropdown list, a courseID should be selected in HiddenField/textbox/label

how to do that

here is a code i tried::

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string select = "select * from courses";
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("-- Select Course --");
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    DataTable dt = con.select_command(select);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    }        

}
```

in dropdownlist i'm getting values in Page Load method

i also tried dropdownlist_selectedindex change method too to select courseID

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LLabel1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

what i'm doing wrong ???

Comment: Is AutoPostBack = true on the DropDownList?  Also, wrap your code in the page_load in if (!IsPostBack) { }

Comment: Please show your current real code (page_load and index changed handler if any)

Comment: yes it did the trick but again it giving me name of course i want to save courseID in hiddenField and it selecting only 1st indexValue, i mean if i select scince from dropdown it should store its id from database which i 1,and if i select commerce it shuld store its id which is 2

Comment: @ClaudioRedi this is a full code i wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a block of  `if (!IsPostBack)` before you update the dropdown in your page_load
The problem is that your code will re-populate the dropdown menu after the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event will be triggred.

That will make a post request to the server and he will run the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` function attached to the `IndexChange` event and then  `page_load`

because the page suppose to be loaded again 
and will result in a new selected value that will not be what you expect it to be.

One more thing: use string identifiers when getting a value from a Row of a DataTable the code will be much more friendly that way. (Readability is very important...)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    string select = "select * from courses";
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("-- Select Course --");
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    DataTable dt = con.select_command(select);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["CourseName"].ToString());
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = dt.Rows[i]["CourseID"].ToString();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = dt.Rows[i]["CourseName"].ToString();
    }
    }        

}
```

Comment: your idea did the trick but i want to print integer value "CourseID" when i select course name from dropdown

Comment: by printing an integer value you mean you want to place the number as the text of a certain label ?

Comment: yes now its working thanks i was missing the !isPostBack block

Comment: Glad that works for you .. most importantly you have to understand the asp.net page life cycle that way you will know when it is required and when it is not .. if that worked please accept the answer ..

Answer (score 0):

try this 
above code you manually add item to dropdownlist so you have to add datavalue as well as

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if(!Ispostback)
            {
            string select = "select * from courses";
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("-- Select Course --","0");

            DataTable dt = con.select_command(select);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new listitem(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(),dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        ));

            }        
                DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
  }
```

and your select index change event

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LLabel1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```